# No linear relation amongst modular forms of different weights when looking at them as holomorphic functions

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-forms

It's just normally stated that it's simple to see this fact in most books, but it does not appear so simple to me.

Comment: Hint: let Tf=g and then write the functional equations for both. You can't pass the linear function through the functional equation because the weights are different.

Comment: Pedantic comment: you meant among *nonzero* modular forms of different weights...

Comment: @StellaBiderman that is the thing that I have not been able to prove. i got to the part that different weight modular forms will give rise to different sort of a functional equation, but how does that tell me that it is not satisfied. And yeah, these are non zero modular forms.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the best way to convince yourself of this is to think of a modular form of weight $k$ as a function on lattices $\Lambda \subset \mathbb C$, which is homogeneous of weight $-k$ for the action of $\mathbb C^\times$, i.e. $f(\lambda \Lambda ) = \lambda^{-k} f(\Lambda)$. This is related to the definition in terms of the variable $\tau$ by $f(\tau) = f(\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z)$; then $f\left(\frac{a\tau + b}{c \tau + d}\right) = f(\mathbb Z + \frac{a\tau + b}{c \tau + d} \mathbb Z) = (c\tau+d)^k f(\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z) = (c\tau+d)^k f(\tau)$ is the usual transformation rule.

If $f_0, \dots, f_k$ are modular forms, not all zero, and such that $f_i$ has weight $i$, then there exists a lattice $\Lambda$ for which $f_1(\Lambda), \dots, f_k(\Lambda)$ are not all zero. But if

$$\sum f_i = 0,$$

then for any $\lambda \in \mathbb C^\times$ we have

$$\sum f_i(\lambda \Lambda) = 0,$$

i.e.

$$\sum \lambda^{-i} f_i(\Lambda) = 0.$$

If we pick $k+1$ distinct elements $\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_k \in \mathbb C^\times$, the $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ matrix $(\lambda_i^{-j})_{0 \leq {i},j \leq k}$ is invertible (being a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)); and hence the system of equations

$$\sum \lambda_j^{-i} f_i(\Lambda) = 0$$

implies that $f_i(\Lambda) = 0$ for all $i$, contradicting the choice of $\Lambda$. Hence no such linear relation is possible.